# Slider in Highcharts similar to Google Playground

Tags: jquery, highcharts

On the following google playground link there is a slider changing piechart. I just want to know whether such option is pre built in Highcharts or I have to write it by own.

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#simple_dashboard

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts doesn't have built-in slider. You have to create that slider for your own, and connect that slider with Highcharts `chart.series[0].setData(data);` function, see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData() (especially last example).